Can I redefine org-babel-execute for specific org-babel blocks?
When I C-c C-c on an org-babel plantuml block, I get the message:
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "No org-babel-execute function for plantuml!")

I have to M-x plantuml-preview-current-block

What does the last sentence mean?

And what's the relation between the question and the title? They seem disconnected from each other.

Add plantuml to your languages in your init file:
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '(
    ...
    (plantuml . t)
    ...
))

Or add a require to your init file:
(require 'ob-plantuml)

Or load the library by hand:
M-x load-library RET ob-plantuml RET

You also have to have the JAR for plantuml installed on your system and you need to customize org-plantuml-jar-path to point to it.
If you want to edit the block with C-c ', you will also need to (require 'plantuml-mode). If you don't have the plantuml-mode package installed, you will first need to install it from ELPA/MELPA.
